# Building React Native iOS app in Azure pipeline gets stuck at “Compiling LaunchScreen.storyboard”

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Just as the title says, I tried to set up the Azure pipeline that will be used to build my iOS app created with React Native. Installing dependencies, pods, certificates, it all goes well and everything seems to work until pipeline gets to the build task which gets stuck at the:

```
▸ Linking MyApp
▸ Compiling LaunchScreen.storyboard
```

At that point, nothing happens for an hour until pipeline is eventually cancelled. For an extra context, building my app through Xcode works perfectly.

This is what my build task looks like.

```
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: "Xcode build IPA (production)"
  inputs:
    actions: 'build -verbose'
    configuration: 'Release'
    sdk: 'iphoneos15.5'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/MyApp.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'MyApp'
    packageApp: true
    exportPath: 'output/package'
    archivePath: 'output/archive'
    signingOption: 'manual'    
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    xcodeVersion: 'specifyPath'
    xcodeDeveloperDir: '/Applications/Xcode_13.4.1.app/Contents/Developer'
```

If you have any idea what might be the problem, please let me know. Thanks!